# How to Check Download/Upload Speed to Web Server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, web-server, performance, upload, page-speed

I have a web server in the US (MS Windows 2008).
Chinese users are complaining of slow speeds and SQL command timeouts. Other Asian and European users are not.
How do I check the speed (download/upload) from Beijing to this particular web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try installing SpeedTest mini (http://www.speedtest.net/mini.php) on your web server and then connect to it from your various locations.

Answer (score 0):

Since SpeedTest mini is no longer being offered for download. You can self-hosted HTML5 Speedtest from https://github.com/adolfintel/speedtest

This is the demo site to see how it works: http://speedtest.fdossena.com/